# Calculating new value of CSS variable based on existing value

Tags: css, css-variables, css-calc, css-cascade

How do I recalculate a new value of a CSS variable (custom property) in a sub-element using `calc()` to modify the value inherited from a parent element?

This doesn’t work:

```css
div {
  height: var(--foo);
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.a {
  --foo: 100px;
}

.b {
  --foo: calc(var(--foo) - 25px);
}
```

```html
<div class=a>
  <div class=b>
    foo box
  </div>
</div>
```

The browser seems to completely unset the value of `--foo` on `.b`.

Using the `inherit` keyword in the `calc()` expression also doesn’t work.

Comment: you cannot do this using CSS variables, better describe what's your end goal to get workarounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenters have noted, this is not currently possible. However, the CSS WG [recently voted to add `inherit` as a function to the CSS Values spec,](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2864) which will make this possible once it’s supported by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly modify the value of a CSS variable that is inherited from a parent element. However, you can achieve this by using a different approach: setting a new CSS variable specifically for the sub-element and use that variable to calculate the desired value:

```
div {
  height: var(--foo);
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.a {
  --foo: 100px;
}

.b {
  /* Set a new variable for the sub-element */
  --sub-foo: calc(var(--foo) - 25px);
  /* Use the new variable instead of modifying --foo */
  height: var(--sub-foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the custom property (variable) and then declare the height with the classes

```css
div {
  --foo: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.a {
  height: var(--foo);
}

.b {
  height: calc(var(--foo) - 25px);
}
```

```html
<div class=a>
  <div class=b>
    foo box
  </div>
</div>
```